# Trouble implementing fade and slide script

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, implementation

I have created a fade and slide script found here below that I am having trouble trying to implement to my website. The script doesn't run and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Script
https://jsfiddle.net/5bj4gf5v/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ZeroSecDelay').delay(500).animate({opacity:1, top: -100}, 'slow', function() {
    });
    return false;
});
```

Page I am trying to implement it too
http://digitalmedia.rocks/contact-me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Window onload instead of DOM ready.

- document.ready runs when the DOM is ready, e.g. all elements are
  there to be found/used, but not necessarily all content.
- window.onload fires later when images and all page content are loaded

Animation should work, also you try to increase delay to fit animation after page load.

```css
.ZeroSecDelay {
  position:relative;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideUp ZeroSecDelay">
<a href="https://twitter.com/dmrocksuk" target="_blank"><img src="http://digitalmedia.rocks/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/img/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter" width="64px" height="64px" /></a>
</div>

<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('.ZeroSecDelay').delay(500).animate({opacity:1, top: -100}, 'slow', function() {
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! Any recommended reading material for jQuery? It is my weakest point as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Tricks site have good jquery and front end tricks. Try it out.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/